# Put text and image side by side and aligned vertically with the navbar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox

I want the text to be side by side with the image aligned with the nav bar logo. But it seems like the image is taking up all the space, I didn't add a smaller width, because I want the image to be that size but with the text next to it. What should I do, guys? why the image is not inside the HomeContent? it looks like it has it own container [image]

```js
// Home.jsx
import React from 'react';
import { FaWhatsapp } from 'react-icons/fa';
import pessoa from '../assets/banner-pessoa.png';
import { HomeContainer, HomeContent } from '../styles/Home.style';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <HomeContainer>
      <HomeContent>
        <div>
          <h3>
            Unindo tecnologia e ciência a serviço da <strong>sua beleza</strong>
          </h3>
          <p>
            Protocolos exclusivos com equipamentos avançados de alta tecnologia e profissionais capacitados, entregando resultados excelentes em tratamentos corporais e faciais.
          </p>
          <div>
            <button>
              <FaWhatsapp />
              Agendar Consulta
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img src={pessoa} alt="uma mulher" />
      </HomeContent>
    </HomeContainer>
    
  );
};

export default Home;
```

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

export const HomeContainer = styled.div`
    width: 100%;
    height: 640px;
    background-color: var(--beige-100);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
`;

export const HomeContent = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    
`;
```

Comment: Your React JSX is irrelevant, what HTML does the browser see once the render is completed? What CSS - including any *relevant* CSS from ancestor elements - does the browser receive, and work with? While you've posted code - and, genuinely, thank you! - the code doesn't help us reproduce the problem, and it doesn't allow us to demonstrate our attempted solutions in any answers we might provide. Please, read the guidance on "*[ask]*," and "*[mcve]*."

Answer (score 1):

You put the image as a element, could use as a background image for the text container.

Anyway, if you want the image as a element and the text beside it, you will need to put the image or the text container as a absolute element and control it width.

If you want they side-by-side, you need to control they size (width: 50% for example).

Answer (score 1):

Your *"text and image side by side"* request instantly reminded me of the lesser known CSS property **shape-outside** which is used like this...

```
.element {  
  float: left;
  shape-outside: circle(50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

The beauty of this property is that the image doesn't necessarily have to be a rectangle, it could be a star yet the text will render perfectly on the shape’s outline.

Here's an easy to follow example of **shape-outside**...

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/